# I want to find the correct way for using object oriented in php

Tags: php

why this code does not print the value.

```
class Test{
    var $i;
    function Test($i){
        $this->i=$i;
    }

    function func1(){
        echo $i;
    }
}

$ob1=new Test(4);
$ob1->func1();  
?>
```

Here I am using object oriented concept

Comment: You can learn here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php. Look for "magic methods".

Comment: @elclanrs What do *magic methods* have to do with this question?

Comment: @elclanrs There is no problem using `function Test()` rather than `__construct`

Comment: Right, right, just saying.

Comment: FYI In modern PHP, constructors are named `__construct`. You should change `function Test($i)` to `public function __construct($i)`

Comment: @C.Malet [unless you are using namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php): "As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes."

Comment: You're using PHP4-style objects... don't

Comment: I absolutely hate when the accepted answer is exactly the same as a higher-voted, earlier answer. FYI, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18526307/283366) was first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
function func1(){
    echo $i;
}
```

with

```
function func1(){
    echo $this->i;
}
```

and will work fine try to learn using
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm

Answer (score 5):

You should echo `$this->i` not `$i`

```
function func1() {
   echo $this->i;
}
```

#### Output

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

See [*The Basics* from the Classes and Objects section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) of the PHP language reference.

> The pseudo-variable `$this` is available when a method is called from within an object context. `$this` is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called [statically](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) from the context of a secondary object).

So use

```
function func1(){
        echo $this->i;
    }
```